# try to setTimeout to show and hide the balls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asynchronous

I tried to write a program to practice my js skills. There are 3 balls and they are hidden at first. I want the ball_1 shows up first, and after 1 sec, ball_1 disappears. Next, ball_2 shows up and after 1 sec it disappears; same logic goes with ball_3. When I run my code, the first two balls does not hide.  I am not sure what is going wrong.  The code below are the html, css, and js code that i wrote.  Hope someone could help me out.  Thank you in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var notes = ['ball_1', 'ball_2', 'ball_3'];
  for (i = notes.length; i > 0; i--) {
    var note = notes.shift();
    $('#' + note).addClass('shown');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#' + note).removeClass('shown');
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
#ball_1 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000000;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#ball_2 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #0000FF;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#ball_3 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #7FFF00;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#ball_1,
#ball_2,
#ball_3 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.not_shown {
  display: none;
}
.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="ball">
  <div id="ball_1" class="not_shown"></div>
  <div id="ball_2" class="not_shown"></div>
  <div id="ball_3" class="not_shown"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an *asnychronous* play of events - first `ball_1` shows up for 1 sec and *after* that `ball_2` shows up for 1 sec and so forth.

Something like this won't work:

```
    for( var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++){
        $('#' + notes[i]).addClass('shown');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#' + notes[i]).removeClass('shown');
        },1000);
    }
```

because the `timeout`s will be registered one after the other in quick succession and all the balls will show up and hide *in little over one second*.

So you can create a `callback` and set the timeout for the next ball only after the previous ball has been shown fully for 1 sec - see demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var notes = ['ball_1', 'ball_2', 'ball_3'];
  hideBall(notes,0);
});

function hideBall(notes,i) {
  $('#' + notes[i]).addClass('shown');
  hide(function() {
    if(++i < notes.length) {
      hideBall(notes,i);
    } 
  }, notes[i]);
}

function hide(callback, note) {
   setTimeout(function() {
      $('#' + note).removeClass('shown');
      callback();
   }, 1000);
}
```

```css
#ball_1 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000000;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#ball_2 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #0000FF;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#ball_3 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #7FFF00;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#ball_1,
#ball_2,
#ball_3 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.not_shown {
  display: none;
}
.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="ball">
  <div id="ball_1" class="not_shown"></div>
  <div id="ball_2" class="not_shown"></div>
  <div id="ball_3" class="not_shown"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me understand the concept of "callback".  I never learned it before. I have a question that in the "hide" functon, there is a function "callback()”. Is this a built-in method in javascript because I did not see you write the function. The second question is that three balls are shown in the same place.  Is there any way to let ball_1 shown on the top position and ball_2 shown in the middle and ball_3 in the bottom just like the order rewritten in the html?  Again thank you so much!!

Comment: `callback()` is the same as the parameter `callback` of the function, for the other doubt, you can use `visibility: visible` and `visibility: hidden` instead of toggling `display`.... let me know if you face issue implementing :)

Comment: thank you for replying.  I found it is kind of challenging for me to fully understand.  So basically callback() is actually hideball()? So i can think of hideball() is calling itself after a while?

Comment: nope, `callback()` is the first parameter of the function `hide(callback, note) {`...

Answer (score 2):

In general never modify an array when iterating using a for loop.  The shift method will remove the first item from the array thus modifying it's length.  Instead do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var notes = ['ball_1','ball_2','ball_3'];
  var i; // You were declaring "i" in global namespace before.  Don't do that.
  for(i = 0; i < notes.length; i++){
    var note = notes[i];
    $('#' + note).addClass('shown');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#' + note).removeClass('shown');
      },1000);
    }
});
```

Also you will see from my note that you were defining "i" in the global namespace.  It is never good to do that so always make sure to define your variables at the beginning of the function block if using "var".

EDIT:  missed a semicolon

EDIT2: completely missed that i needed to change up the loop condition.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you need

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var notes = ['ball_1','ball_2','ball_3'];
    for(i = notes.length; i > 0; i--){
        var note = notes[i];
        $('#' + note).addClass('shown');
        hideBall(note, i)
    }
});

function hideBall(note) {
    setTimeout(function() {
       $('#' + note).removeClass('shown');
    },1000 * i);
}
```

```css
#ball_1{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#ball_2{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #0000FF;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
}


#ball_3{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #7FFF00;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#ball_1, #ball_2, #ball_3 {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.not_shown {
    display: none;
}

.shown {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "ball">
        <div id = "ball_1" class = "not_shown"></div>
        <div id = "ball_2" class = "not_shown"></div>
        <div id = "ball_3" class = "not_shown"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank u.  But what I want is to show the ball_1 and disappear after 1 sec; then ball_2 shows up and disappear after 1 sec, etc

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying won't work as it will run the for loop all in one go, setting up 3x timeouts.

try something like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
function myBallLoop(){
     // increment as needed
     if(typeof note == 'undefined') {
        var note = 1;
     } else if (note == 3){
        break; // end loop
     } else {
        note ++;
     }
        // show current ball qickly
        $('#ball_' + note).show('fast', function(){
            // call back after show event
            // hide current ball after 1 sec
            r = setTimeout(function(){$('#ball_' + note).hide()}, 1000);
            // self call function after 2 seconts
            t = setTimeout(function(){myBallLoop();, 2000}
       });           

     }
   // loop start
   myBallLoop();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of what jquery gives you.

Iterate using $.each is also the same as ES5's forEach. Using delay method to delay a function of adding classes is similar to setTimeout.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  var notes = ['ball_1','ball_2','ball_3'];

  let showBalls = (i, item) => {
    $('#' + item).delay(i * 1000).queue(() => {
      $('#' + item).addClass('shown');
      $('#' + notes[i - 1]).removeClass('shown').clearQueue();
    });
  }
  $.each(notes, (i, item) => {
    showBalls(i, item);
  });
});
```

```css
#ball_1{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000000;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#ball_2{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #0000FF;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


#ball_3{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #7FFF00;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#ball_1, #ball_2, #ball_3 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.not_shown {
  display: none;
}

.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id = "ball">
  <div id = "ball_1" class = "not_shown"></div>
  <div id = "ball_2" class = "not_shown"></div>
  <div id = "ball_3" class = "not_shown"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Herman for helping me.  I apologize for not making it clear.  I want the black ball shows up and after 1 sec, black ball disappear.  Next, blue ball shows up and after 1 sec it disappear; same logic goes with green ball.

Comment: @vkosyj updated my answer for you. Hope it helps also. :)

Comment: Thank you again Herman. However, the green ball is still there.  Is there anyway to make it disappear as well? Thank you so much.  I just learned a little about js not two much about jquery.  I have to learn those fancy symbol like "=>".